# How, from a cmd, start a new cmd instance and run a command within?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, powershell, cmd.exe

I need to run two commands which never terminate. What I normally do is to

- start a `cmd` terminal and type in the first command
- start another `cmd` terminal and type in the second command

I then have my two processes running in parallel.

I now would like to automate this by having one "startup" file which would lauch the two terminals above. It can be `cmd` or PowerShell based.

**Note 1:** I tried to use `cmd` with `/k` or `/c` but this does not spawn a new terminal. Trying something like `cmd /c cmd` ended up with `Internal Error` output in the shell.

**Note 2:** PowerShell has [Background Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288(v=vs.85).aspx). The problem is that I want to have two separate shells I can monitor the output on (and eventually close the running process with `Ctrl-C`.

**Is there a way to achieve this in one file?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Create a batch file:

```
start cmd.exe /c <first command>
start cmd.exe /c <second command>
```

Run the batch file and it will open the two cmd windows and the batch file will exit.

Comment: What does the "/c" flag stand for?

Comment: @BrunoBieri `/c` tells `cmd` to run the command then exit. As opposed to `/k` that tells `cmd` to run the command and remain open - basically sit at the command prompt. If you need help with command line switches you can use `cmd /?`.

Comment: What if the commands I want to pass to cmd are batch files themselves ?

Comment: @Charles just specify the batch file name in place of the command name. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 'start cmd /c dir' is what you're looking for.
edit: Well, /k for short example like dir, but 'start' is the magic word you need.

Answer (score 0):

*emphasized text*Quote from Ren "I believe 'start cmd /c dir' is what you're looking for."

I personally think that 'start cmd /c dir /s' would be even better

Comment: Or  'start cmd /c dir /s /p' would be Even Better than both of those heh

Comment: SORRY I JUST REALIZED THIS OLD AF ANYWAYS LOL!! WHAT AM I EVEN DOING ON THE SUPERFICIAL WEB NE WHO INSTEAD OF THE DW??? I'VE LOST IT!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).